# Como organizar os métodos CRUD para cada tabela?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, classes, jdbc

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de organizar os métodos CRUD (create, read, update, delete) de cada classe em Java.

Um exemplo, pra ficar melhor pra entender:

Suponhamos que temos as classes `Funcionario`, `Cliente` e `Produto`.

Cada uma dessas classes refere-se a uma tabela no banco de dados, ou seja, uma para funcionário, outra pra cliente e outra para produtos.

Minha pergunta é:

É recomendado/melhor colocar os métodos CRUD relacionados a cada classe nelas mesmas ou se é melhor fazer uma classe com todas as operações de banco de dados.

Por exemplo: `IncluirFuncionario()`, `IncluirCliente()` e `IncluirProduto()`.

É melhor colocar cada um na sua classe ou fazer uma outra chamada `OperacoesBD`, que contenha todas as operações para todas as classe?

Eu peguei o costume de por tudo em uma classe só, pois daí eu utilizava e inicializava apenas uma vez a variável `java.sql.Connection connection` no construtor da classe.

Comment: Acho que essa pergunta é muito ampla, eu recomendo que você de uma boa olhada nos Design Patterns do Java, veja esta apostila da Caelum: https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Penso que você deve manter as coisas em seu escopo. O que tem a ver com funcionário, deve estar na classe de funcionário, cliente em cliente, e assim por diante. Imagine um cenário onde você tenha 50 entidades (comum). Pra cada um deles, um CRUD básico. Tua classe terá 200 métodos, pra começar...

Você pode tirar esses métodos da própria classe, deixando o objeto independente de questões relacionadas ao banco de dados, mas ainda assim deve criar classes separadas, especializadas, no contexto do banco para cuidar dessa persistência. Resumidamente, separar os modelos do layer de dados.

Quanto a manter somente uma instancia da conexão com o banco, você pode usar classes estáticas, singleton, ou outro desenho que te permita isso. Mas fique atento a problemas referentes a concorrência e limitações do uso compartilhado e talvez intenso dessa instância.

Como gosto - pessoal - quase sempre trabalho no seguinte sentido:

-classe do objeto: uma classe POCO, sem nenhuma dependência de ninguém. Posso usar ela na minha camada de exibição e onde mais eu quiser dentro da aplicação.

-classe de persistência do objeto: um layer com classes que têm os métodos de CRUD e, obviamente, conhece a classe POCO. Cada classe conhece o objeto do escopo correspondente, fazendo o mapeamento pro banco de dados.

-classe de conexão com o banco: somente instanciada dentro da classe de persistência, com os controles da conexão.

Veja que, nesse cenário, se eu por ventura quiser trocar de banco de dados, apenas mudo a classe que diz respeito a este escopo, da conexão, e nada muda no resto. Pense em camadas!